# how read cookie without turn off httpOnly

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

so i do a little project in react front and back
now i crate a cookie when i login to the web and save him in the client

now i went to do a condition on if cookie exit or not exists
so i try to get and read the cookie but the problem is I must to set httpOnly=false when I create the cookie to success get the cookie but I know its create a secure problem

i tried with "react-cookie" "js-cookie" and docoment.cookie

so how i cab get and read cookie in secure way

Comment: The security issue you are talking about is when javascript code can read the cookie. That is why `httpOnly` does not allow **ANY** javascript code (regardless if you wrote it yourself or is a React library) to read the cookie. If no javascript code can read the cookie then 3rd party code cannot read the cookie. But this obviously mean that your own code also cannot read the cookie. The only solution is to redesign your logic so that you don't need to check if the cookie exists.

Comment: ok I understend so lets say i went check if user login or not whice way you suggest

Comment: The simple way is to have the login API return something that you can save in your front-end. I normally have the login API return the user profile so that I can display the user's name in the UI and handle user roles correctly. Your javascript code does not need the cookie at all. The **ONLY** use of the cookie is to allow the backend to detect if the user is logged it and allow access to protected API endpoints. You don't need to manage the cookie. The browser will automatically manage the cookie for you as long as it's still valid.

Comment: Thanks bro, I got it
I will try to work on it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @slebetman I crate in my backend an api that return the user are logged in but i dont understand how i handle it all the time in the front end so the front know always if the user is stiil logged in or mybe is looged out Example on my login page If I log in successfully I go to the home page and then I want my navBer component to show me the name of the logged in user and not the login button that takes me to the login page
The problem is that I have to refresh the page for it to be updated

Comment: The back-end will either respond normally or respond with an authorization error (either with status 401 - Unauthorized or 403 - Forbidden or with normal 200 OK status but with the error encoded in JSON data). Say for example the user is trying to get a list of messages and make a request to `/api/messages`. If the session has expired or the user is not logged in the backend will respond with an error then your front-end logic will execute it's logout logic (eg, delete the logged_in status from localstorage or delete the user profile data from localstorage etc.)

Comment: This is how websites like Facebook work. It always assume you're not logged in. If you are logged in then it saves your profile data in localStorage and if your profile data exists in localStorage it assumes you're logged in. If any response from the backend says that the user is unauthorized it deletes all user data from localStorage and goes back to its default behavior of always assuming you're not logged in.

Comment: So if I understood correctly.
To begin with, the user logs in as not logged in to the home page for which he has permission, then when the user logs in, the client saves the cookie and the information that the user is logged in in local storage
Then in case of error (expired or something like that)
Should the information in Local Storg be deleted?
And basically in every API request I have to define that in the event of an error the data in the locale should be deleted?